# Why is this not inserting into mysqli database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I can not figure out why this is not adding the content to the DB.  I need to add the itemcode and item into the database then be able to read it.  This is what i have:

**add.php**

```
include('dbconnect.php');
function get_posts() {
    $txtitemcode = (!empty($_POST['itemcode']) ? $_POST['itemcode'] : null);
    $txtitem = (!empty($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : null);
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO barcode (itemcode, item) VALUES ('".$txtitemcode."','".$txtitem."')";
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql1))
    {
        die('Error:'.mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "<h1>record added</h1>;
    window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

**dbconnect.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","db1");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "Connected to Database. Please Continue.";
}
```

Is anyone able to help?? This is weird to me that it is not working.

Comment: Apart from Clayton's answer below, you should make sure that get_posts() is not called if there is a connection error. Your code prints the error code if it cannot connect to the database, but you do not do anything else subsequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling your insert query from inside of a function yet $con is in the global scope.  To include `$con` within your function you must do this:

```
include('dbconnect.php');
function get_posts() {
    global $con;
    $txtitemcode = (!empty($_POST['itemcode']) ? $_POST['itemcode'] : null);
    $txtitem = (!empty($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : null);
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO barcode (itemcode, item) VALUES ('".$txtitemcode."','".$txtitem."')";
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql1))
    {
        die('Error:'.mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "<h1>record added</h1>;
    window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
}
get_posts(); // you can call get_posts() here

mysqli_close($con);
```

Basically, `global` is a PHP keyword that will allow you to access variables that have been defined in the global scope.  [Read about in the documentation by clicking here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> [..] within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

And, be sure to call your function, it is as simple as typing the following:

```
get_posts();
```

Comment: It would not hurt if the php code actualy executed the get_posts() function. We do not even know if it has been called at all.

Comment: @DrakeMadigan, are you calling get_posts() anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Clayton the code I have above is the only code I have in the add.php

Comment: @DrakeMadigan I just added a line to the code sample that will call the function

Comment: @Clayton I feel like an idiot now. I have been messing with that all day. I have been reading on php and mysqli and could not figure that out. Thank you very much. That fixed it.

Comment: It  may be simpler to remove the get_posts() function  completely, just leave what is in the function's body in the page's code. It would not decrease the quality of the code...